# Toggle the element - Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am struggling with Selenium.

Basically I want to click on the following element to toggle the element:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
   <a class=" mr-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown-ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).closest('.btn-group').toggleClass('open');"
     <svg class="">
         <use xlink:href="resources/icons/settings.svg#Layer_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     </svg>
    </a>
```

It changes to:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right open”>
    <a class=" mr-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown-ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).closest('.btn-group').toggleClass('open');">
      <a class=" mr-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown-ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).closest('.btn-group').toggleClass('open');">
        <svg class="">  
           <use xlink:href="resources/icons/settings.svg#Layer_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          </svg>
       </a>
```

The method I wrote for clicking this element:

```
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='btn-group.pull-right’]”));
dropDown.click();
```

However, I am getting an Exception:

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='btn-group.pull-right']"}

Any recommendations on why I am geting this exception?

Comment: share the website link or the html source

Comment: `//div[contains(@class, 'btn-group') and contains(@class, 'pull-right')]` ?

Comment: <div class="headerMenu hidden-sm-down  col-md-6 col-xl-8 pull-right">
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
<a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class=" mr-2" data-toggle="dropdown-ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).closest('.btn-group').toggleClass('open');">
<svg class="">
 <use xlink:href="resources/icons/settings.svg#Layer_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use>
</svg></a>
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
<select class="ml-2 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="theme"

Comment: onchange="$(this).closest('.btn-group').removeClass('open')">
<!----><option value="styles/vendor/anthem.blue.theme.css">Blue Theme</option><option value="styles/vendor/anthem.black.theme.css">Black Theme</option>

</select>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="$(this).closest('.btn-group').removeClass('open')">My Profile</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).closest('.btn-group').removeClass('open')"> Logout</a>
</div></div>

Comment: If you are trying to click on the node returned by `findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='btn-group.pull-right’]”));` a small change of `’` to `'` just after `btn-group.pull-right` should work.

Comment: Incase you are trying to click on the node `<use xlink:href="resources/icons/settings.svg#Layer_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` consider how to click on elements within `svg` tag

Comment: Thank you Debanjan, it works when I am trying to click on the node. Thank you for your helo

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'or' logical operator in ur xapth which locate both.

Try this Xpath :-`By.xpath("//div[@class='btn-group.pull-right’|//div[@class='btn-group pull-right open’ "]`

Comment: I am still getting the following error:
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@class='btn-group.pull-right’]|//div[@class='btn-group.pull-right.open’] because of the following error:

Comment: can u share ur url ?

Comment: URL is blocked by employer, if used outside of work machine, Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

your html shows element has class  "class="btn-group pull-right" "
and your xpath "By.xpath(" //div[@class='btn-group.pull-right’]”" if i closely look at it your are adding dot in the xpath to remove space which is not required when using xpath, spaces will be removed by dot in css. So try using this xpath
//div[@class='btn-group pull-right’]